# Set proxy value into InfoBip API

Tags: java, proxy, sms, infobip, infobip-api

Good day,

I have download the `infobip` API and import it to my workspace.

I would to like to use this API to call to `infobip` to send SMS.

However, I have a requirement, which is, I need to go through server proxy first before reach to `infobip` endpoint URL.

So, the original code is as follow:

```
 public SMSResponse execute(SMSTextualRequest bodyObject) {
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder( ).
                .setEndpoint( configuration.getBaseUrl( ) )
                .setRequestInterceptor( getRequestInterceptor( ) )
                .setConverter(
                        new GsonConverter( new GsonBuilder( ).setDateFormat(
                                "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" ).create( ) ) )
                .build( );
        SendSingleTextualSmsService service = restAdapter
                .create( SendSingleTextualSmsService.class );
        return service.execute( bodyObject );
    }
```

I am thinking to use the `setClient()` method to set the proxy value.
So, I create a Client object:

```
Client client = null;
```

And planing to do as follow:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder( ).setClient( client )
\\ some code...
```

However, I find nothing related to ip address, port number attribute for me to set in the `Client` object.

Am I using the correct way?

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure it like this:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
java.net.Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,  new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort));
client.setProxy(proxy);

RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(configuration.getBaseUrl())
            .setRequestInterceptor(getRequestInterceptor())
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(new GsonBuilder()
                                    .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
                                    .create()))
            .setClient(new OkClient(client))
            .build();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Good idea, too bad my server and application are restrict to java 1.6. OkHttpClient require minimum java 1.7. There will be a very big changes in my whole system if upgrade to java 1.7, all the framework need to change, and maybe some code need to change as well.